# Linux NetworkManager not writing resolv.conf or running dhclient

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, dhcp, networkmanager

I'm on a ubuntu based linux distro (linaro) running xfce. My networkmanager connects to wireless access points, but is unable to do two things:

- dynamically acquire a nameserver, and write a dynamic `/etc/resolv.conf`. In fact, it would be great if I could make it do this for some particular networks, and use a standard `/etc/resolv.conf` on other networks.
- My browser does not redirect to login pages. Clearly, this has something to do with the nameserver problem.

I checked my `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` and it has the line

`request subnet-mask, broadcast-address, time-offset, routers,
        domain-name, domain-name-servers, domain-search, host-name,
        netbios-name-servers, netbios-scope, interface-mtu,
        rfc3442-classless-static-routes, ntp-servers,
        dhcp6.domain-search, dhcp6.fqdn,
        dhcp6.name-servers, dhcp6.sntp-servers;`

So if I run

`sudo dhclient <network inteface>`

it rewrites the `/etc/resolv.conf` file without any trouble. So if I "connect manually" using wpa-supplicant and dhclient, this works perfectly. So I'm guessing it's an issue with network manager. Does network manager not use dhclient? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

On my system (ubuntu 14.04), /etc/resolv.conf is created by the package "resolvconf" (is it installed?) and is just a symbolic link to the file ../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf.

The IP address in /etc/resolv.conf is a dummy internal IP. To get the real address of the name server you can use "nm-tool" or "nmcli device list iface eth0".

Which method did you choose in Network-mananger under the IPv4, "Automatic (DHCP)" or "Automatic (DHCP) addresses only". I think you have to use the first one.

What is the version of you linaro system and on which version of ubuntu is it based?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that newer versions of NetworkManager use a program called dnsmasq as a DNS resolver. So even if you delete the 

  `/etc/resolv.conf`

file from your system, NetworkManager will work correctly. In fact, dnsmasq has an explicit option to NOT read `resolv.conf`. This is what my NetworkManager usually runs it with:

  `dnsmasq --no-resolv`

It also has a 

  `/var/run/nm-dns-dnsmasq.conf`

file. This is configured using files in the 

  `/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d/`

Look at the dnsmasq documentation to learn more about its configuration. It appears to be a fairly powerful tool.

dnsmasq can be disabled by removing the line

  `dns=dnsmasq`

in the

  `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`

file. Then --although I've not tested it-- it ought to default to dhclient, based on what I've read in the NetworkManager documentation.

Another possible problem was that the /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf had a line that said

  `[ifupdown]
  managed=false`

I changed this to true, and NetworkManager started to work again properly. The newer NetworkManager versions (on precise and later) also tend to pause for 60 or more seconds in the beginning with a 

`waiting for network configuration`

message during boot. This is usually cause by a syntax error in the `/etc/network/interfaces` file. I fixed this by having just the following lines in the file

`auto lo
iface lo inet loopback`